# Is there any disadvantage of making software update and upgrade automatic?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, cron, software-updates

On Lubuntu 18.04, Software Updater notifies me there is update available from time to time. If I happen to have the time to, I will manually run `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`.

I am thinking about whether to make the update and upgrade automatically happen. 
Is there any disadvantage of making software update and upgrade automatic?  Would the convenience outweigh the disadvantage?

When making software update and upgrade automatic,  which way is better:

- changing the settings of Software Updater, or
- creating an anacron daily job `apt update; apt upgrade`?

Thanks.

Comment: Related tag: [tag:unattended-upgrades]

Comment: Related Debian wiki page: [Unattended Upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades).

Answer (score 6):

In production systems, depending on how critical your services/systems are, and how you have high availability setup, you *might not want to have scheduled/unattended automatic upgrades*.

Over the years, I have seen services outages on several services due to people doing automatic upgrades:

- squid going out due to a new upgraded minor version having a slight different syntax;
- DNS services going out due to a dynamic routing daemon stopping supporting sysV in a minor release;
- Apache services down t due to lack of disk space in an already tested package;
- Apache not restarting due to an update recreating a default file...
- Apache restarting but the update replacing the main page of a site with Apache default page;
- DHCP services malfunction due to a bug in a minor release;
- netflow services stopping for days due to someone placing a compiled binary on the place of the official binary of a package;
- rsyslog going down due rsyslog changing some syntax and someone having setting up a backport repository without knowing well what was doing;
- FreeRadius services going down after pushing an untested version to a local repository and not knowing someone setup a Radius with automatic upgrades.

Also when doing major releases upgrades blindly, you can have issues into software/applicational incompatibilities between software and versions.

As @panki also correctly points out, often you cannot upgrade blindly software and introduce shorter or more prolonged outages while it is upgraded, or worse, prolonged outages until a human corrects some minor (or major) hiccup that happened during the upgrade.

While automatic upgrades may be interesting for a desktop/home server setting, the instability trade off that it brings to production systems does not make it worthwhile using them. I would classify that is one of those things that while it works, it appears to save you a lot of hassle, however when it fails, it does let you down in unpredictable ways.

As for ways to mitigate/manage the upgrade life cycle, you can employ several strategies, also depending on your uptime requirements/infra-structure size:

- simply doing it manually:
- doing it semi-automatically with someone supervising the process;
- monitoring all the services and the person supervising the process, after revising all the upgrade logs, keeping on eye on the monitoring services;
- doing some planning into what upgrades are critical or not, and not doing them blindly;
- using different releases of Linux in redundant systems (more work and more possible different things go wrong...);
- using redundancy/test beds for services and doing phased upgrades;
- employing point-in-time "bookmarked" releases as for instance, supported by yum;
- using local repositories/proxies to distributed controlled/tested/approved releases akin to Satellite/Katello/Spacewalk for RH/CentOS based systems or [Aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) for Debian;
- integrating those strategies with devops tools like Ansible.

Additionally in production systems, when managing systems that are not your own, you might also have to deal with bureaucratic issues of asking permission to the owners before updating *their systems*, and thus you cannot keep automatic updating services active.

TDLR The management of the operating system upgrade life cycle, in a production environment is anything but simple. There are many angles to the OS upgrade life cycle, operational, system, versioning, security, human, applicational and so on.

Coming back to the specific part of the question, having automatic procedures when high uptime/high reliability is demanded might not be the best of the scenarios.

PS.related, for Debian

> **aptly** is a swiss army knife for Debian repository management: it allows you to mirror remote repositories, manage local package
>   repositories, take snapshots, pull new versions of packages along with
>   dependencies, publish as Debian repository.

Comment: I think it's also important to consider the infrastructure. Say if the server is running a productive database, you might not want to upgrade that while there are app servers actively using it.

Comment: @Panki Indeed, there are many angles to the OS upgrade life cycle, operational, system, versioning, security, human, application and so on. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Thanks. How do you not doing "upgrades blindly"? I am always lost in the screenful output by update and upgrade.

Comment: @Tim making tests in pre-production, taking lists of them, guaranteeing that only those packages are upgraded...you are trying to compare hobby vs corporate....

Comment: `apt upgrade` doesn't take a package name as argument. How would you upgrade only one package?

Comment: @Tim several strategies....local mirrors/mirror snapshots/local repositories/local proxies/naming specific packages+Ansible/scripting/Aptly...see https://www.aptly.info/ for an example of a "official" method/tool

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that a software update will break your system. Do you want this to happen while you are doing something important?

It is possible that someone will hack your system, because you have not installed a security update yet.